pixelated logo when resize it up or down in Photoshop
Lately I have been experiencing problems with Logos.
When insert a logo (png or jpg format) in new workplace, the logo looks great and then when I make it smaller, I will see logo pixelated but not too bad, but then when I make it bigger the logo turned really pixelated, especially the edges. I tried to fix it with online tutorial help but didn't work.
I also tried different logos I have in my file, and I have the same problem.
Can you please help me?
Thank you in advance.
Yule

You make it smaller and then larger?

There is no good generic universal solution to this problem. If you start out with a PNG or JPEG then the size is set in the file. You really should not be using PNG or JPEG you should have a vector version of your logo for use. So logo should have been authored be in PDF, EPS, AI or SVG format.
The question what to do if you don't have a sufficiently good source for logo ranges form recreating the logo, vectorizing, ai upscaling or just accepting that you cant do the size you want.

Turn off resampling under image> Image size.Then set your resolution how you want it to be crisp (300 is high, 72 is low) This will redistribute your dpi instead of spreading them out.
This is primarily done for printing.
